# The return type 'Future<dynamic>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:q/AutherizationState/pages/authMain.dart';
import 'package:q/LoadingState/Pages/ErrPages/mobiledataErr.dart';
import 'package:q/LoadingState/Pages/ErrPages/wifiErr.dart';
import 'Extra/connectionState.dart';

class LoadingMainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadingMainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoadingMainPage> createState() => _LoadingMainPageState();
}

class _LoadingMainPageState extends State<LoadingMainPage> {
  final wifistate = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.asBroadcastStream();
  final checkconn = checkStream().asBroadcastStream();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: wifistate,
            builder: (context, snap) {
              switch (snap.data) {
                case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: checkconn,
                      initialData: false,
                      builder: (context, snap) {
                        if (snap.data == true) {
                          return const AuthMain();
                        } else {
                          return const MobileData();
                        }
                      });

                case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: checkconn,
                      initialData: false,
                      builder: (context, snap) {
                        if (snap.data == true) {
                          return const AuthMain();
                        } else {
                          return const WifiLimited();
                        }
                      });

                case ConnectivityResult.ethernet:
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: checkconn,
                      initialData: false,
                      builder: (context, snap) {
                        if (snap.data == true) {
                          return Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => const AuthMain())); // gives me the error hear
                        } else {
                          return const WifiLimited();
                        }
                      });

                default:
                  return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: checkconn,
                      initialData: false,
                      builder: (context, snap) {
                        if (snap.data == true) {
                          return const AuthMain();
                        } else {
                          return const WifiLimited();
                        }
                      });
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Why this code doesn't work. i want to navigate to another page why this isn't  it working.

what I won't to do is I have AUTH page for login and authorization. first app starts it will look for WIFI and if there isn't WIFI it will return a WIFI err page.  but if every things are ok I want to navigator.push() to AUTH page

Can some one help me with this. I am new to flutter and dart programming

Answer (score 0):

`build` has to return `Widget`. Something like this could work:

```
if (snap.data == true) {
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const AuthMain()));
  return Container();
} else {
  return const WifiLimited();
}
```